# Joining the parent table to its child and get the data from it

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two database. The `parentSub` and `childsub`

parentSub

```
|ID|component_name|weight|actualWeight
 1   a              0        0
 2   b              0        0
 3   c              0        0
 4   d              0        0
 5   e              0        0
 6   f              0        0
```

childSub

```
|parent_iD|category_name|weight|actualWeight
 1          aa              0        0
 2          aaa             0        0
 3          aaaa            0        0
 4          bb              0        0
 5          bbb             0        0
 6          cc              0        0
 7          ccc             0        0
 8          dd              0        0
 9          ee              0        0
 10         ff              0        0
```

As what can you see above the `childSub` have column called parent_iD in that situation. I want to get the column called component_name and after that the childs data must under in the parentSub. Just like this. How can I get the childsub under that specific column. That all `a` must under parent `a`. Using their ID.

```
 a
    aa
    aaa
    aaaa
  b
    bb  
    bbb
  c
    cc
    ccc
  d 
    dd
  e
    ee
  f
    ff
```

I've been using laravel for the framework. The only thing that I've done is to get only the `component_name` column and `category_name`

getColumnController.php

```
 return View::make('view.index')->with('parentSubs',parentSub::get())->with('childSubs',childSubs::get());
```

View

```
<table class="table datatable_simple">
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($parentSubs as $parentSub)
                        <tr> 
                            <td><em>{{{$parentSub->component_name}}}</em></td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
                <tbody>
                   @foreach($childSubs as $childSub)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{{$childsub->survey_question}}}</td>   

                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: what you want is clear.... but what have you tried so far? give us something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
select (select b.component_name from parentSub b where b.ID = a.parent_iD) as component_name ,a.category_name,a.weight,a.actualWeight from childSub a
```

Comment: where I will put this line of code? is it in model or controller?

Comment: @akimebless this is my sql script . If you run this script in mysql then you will  get your desired result. So just check in MySQL first. once everything is ok then you can integrate with your project

Comment: @Ronak-Thank you. Just a quick question. What if this happens, "See above edited file". How can I query it ?

Comment: @akimebless.. I don't have knowledge of PHP. so I can not help on it. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the tables and select the data you want. This will do (without eloquent):

```
$query = DB::table('parentSub')
    ->leftJoin('childSub', 'parentSub.id', '=', 'childSub.parent_id') //Join the child table
    ->get();

var_dump($query); // Dump result
```

Comment: @JasonK- do I have to make a model for it ?

Comment: No you don't have to, in this example I'm using the query builder. If you want to use Eloquent (with model classes), then take a look here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships